# Search text file for user variable - Whats wrong with this code

Tags: c#, file, variables, search, text

Trying to read from a text file based on a user variable entry

my entry has variations (upper/lower case) of the name "Big Fred"

The code runs but I am getting no results back.

The code on my laptop points to specific location which I have removed from the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadTextFileWhile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name you wish to search for: ");                       //Prompt user for the name they wish to search for
            string x = Console.ReadLine();                                                      //assign the name the user inputs as their search parameter to the value of x
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("C:/insert location here");      //Read the the text file at this location and assign to myReader
            string line = "";                                                                   //asssign 'nothing' to line.

            while (line != null)                                                                //while line in the text file is not null (empty)
            {
                line = myReader.ReadLine();                                                     //pass contents of myReader to line
                if (line != null && line == x)                                                  //if contents of line are not null and equal to the variable in x print to screen
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

            myReader.Close();                                                                   //close myReader properly
            Console.ReadLine();                                                                 //Readline to keep console window open allowing a human to read output.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [string.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) and its overload that excludes case differences

```
line = myReader.ReadLine();                                                     
if (line != null && line.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
      Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: That has resolved the issue of none of the results not showing, however it appears to be showing every line from the text file, not just those containing the user variable (there is a Pete and a Bruce within the file for testing puposes and they are showing in the results).

Comment: That's very strange unless you have a different kind of newline separator. You could try to debug what has been read putting a Console.WriteLine(line) before the if statement

Comment: rogue ; causing it to treat the if statement as an empty statement. Cheers Steve!

Answer (score 1):

You just want to match the string in caseInsensitive fashion correct. You can use .Equals

```
if (line.Equals(x,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Another thing is:-
You can use

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) or String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
```

instead of checking if is null

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the every line from the text file is very simple. You might have copied the text content from a web page or some where else.; and there each line is not separated by a new line constant either \n or Environment.NewLine. So what you need to d is either Open the file and after each line press Enter key to manually insert new line OR read all test from the file and Split it by Dot[.] separator and use above code to process it individually. I faced the same prob & now it is working fine.